# My TCP client does not connect to my TCP listener yet telnet works

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, tcpclient, tcplistener

I've got a TCP listener in my server, and a TCP client in my client. Everything works perfectly fine, but when I try to use my server's IP address, everything breaks. I've made sure the port was open, tested it with SimplePortTester, and everything was fine. I have the TCP listener listening on port `1249`, and the TCP client sending / receiving data on port `1249` as well. When I have the TCP client set to 127.0.0.1, it can send data to the server and receive data from it completely flawlessly, but when I put in my machine's IP address into the TCP client, it says that the target machine actively refused it, however, when I telnet to my server, it pops up on the TCP listener as a request, meaning it's not an issue with port forwarding, firewall, antivirus, etc..

The TCP listener code is as follows:

```
TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(1249);
myList.Start();
Console.WriteLine("[SERVER]: Waiting for a connection...");
Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
Console.WriteLine("[CLIENT]: Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);
byte[] b = new byte[100];
int k = s.Receive(b);
Console.WriteLine("[SERVER]: Recieved...");
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
     sb.Append(Convert.ToChar(b[i]));
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

The above code should simply print out the data that the server receives.

The TCP client code is as follows:

```
TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
tcpclnt.Connect("ipAddressHere", 1249);
NetworkStream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();
ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(data);
stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);
```

The above code should simply send data to the server.

The code, when run, throws a `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException`, "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

The majority of the actual code has been removed, however that is just application-specific code that isn't harmful to the server or needed for the question.

Comment: The updated sample works fine for me. Make sure you're using the right IP address/hostname, and note that you shouldn't use `new TcpListener(int port)` either - you should specify what IP address the listener is supposed to listen on. You have no control over where the listener actually listens!

Comment: Do you have some special reason you need to use raw TCP? Because if you just want a few computers to communicate there are a bunch of protocols and libraries that can make it a whole lot easier.

Comment: @JonasH I'm just using the code that worked for me forever ago, however it would be nice to update it. Are there any that you recommend?

Comment: Depends on your purposes. I got MQTT up and running within an hour or so following [this guide](https://dev.to/eduardojuliao/basic-mqtt-with-c-1f88). But you might also consider a webserver, gRPC, rabbitMQ etc.

Comment: Also to say: writing a good TCP server is hard. Like: *really hard*; even if you want "raw" for a custom protocol, I would strongly suggest using Kestrel as the starting point (there is a handler API that lets you offload everything except protocol parsing). And if you don't care about the protocol; just use something like gRPC - then you can ship today. And quite honestly: I have no idea why `TcpClient` and `TcpListener` even *exist* - they add **nothing** over the underlying `Socket` and maybe `NetworkStream` APIs. I write TCP clients/servers *a lot*: never found a single use for them.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
tcpclnt.Connect("ipAddressHere", 1249);
```

is using the `hostname` parameter, which is not the same thing as an IP address; the first thing I'd try would be:

```cs
var ip = IPAddress.Parse("ipAddressHere");
tcpclnt.Connect(ip, 1249);
```

or:

```cs
var ip = IPAddress.Parse("ipAddressHere");
tcpclnt.Connect(new IPEndPoint(ip, 1249));
```

Comment: using `new IPEndPoint(ip, 1249)` unfortunately still threw an error. This one issue has delayed the release of this program for quite a bit 

Comment: @AyeItsAxi what error? We aren't psychic

Comment: @March Gravell Just realized the specific error is not described in the post, my apologies. The error is as follows: `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`